# Matrix transposition in clojure

Tags: clojure, matrix

In Clojure a possible representation of a matrix is a vector of vectors, i.e. `[[1 2] [3 4]]`.
A possible implementation of transposing a matrix would be:

```clojure
(defn transpose [matrix]
  (loop [matrix matrix, transp [], i 0]
    (if (< i (count (nth matrix 0)))
      (recur matrix 
             (conj transp
                   (vec (reduce concat
                                (map #(conj [] (nth %1 i))
                                     matrix))))
             (inc i))
      transp)))
```

Can anyone think of a more idiomatic Clojure implementation? For instance to avoid this horrid loop recur?

Comment: Do you know about incanter? If you need various matrix operations it could be a source of inspiration - https://github.com/liebke/incanter/wiki/matrices

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The usual solution is

```
(defn transpose [m]
  (apply mapv vector m))
```

Comment: This works because `(apply mapv vector m)` is the same as `(mapv vector (m 0) (m 1) ...)`. 
`map`/`mapv` accepts function (`vector`) in this case and any number of collections.
If more than one collection is provided then `map` will apply the function (`vector`) to the first items in those collections, then to the second items, etc.

Comment: note that this crashes given `[]` whereas mikera/core.matrix returns `[]` which seems reasonable

Answer (score 22):

As of 2014, I would recommend using [core.matrix](https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix) for any numerical work in Clojure.

Among other things, this provides implementations of all the most common matrix operations:

```
(use 'clojure.core.matrix)

(transpose [[1 2] [3 4]])
=> [[1 3] [2 4]]
```

Comment: I think you should at least mention that core.matrix is written by you, if you're going to recommend it.

Comment: I would discount that he is the author given the more pertinent fact that the namespace he recommends is prepended with the words "clojure.core"

Comment: This is a valid answer. I don't see how a disclaimer could improve it. ... Arguably, this may not be idiomatic clojure, but optimized libraries are idiomatic for matrix ops.

Comment: You can also try [Neanderthal](http://neanderthal.uncomplicate.org/) - new native-speed matrix library for clojure.