# How to transpose a nested vector in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have the following variable

```
 (def a [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]])
```

and want to return

```
[[1 3 5][2 4 6]]
```

and if input is 
`[[1 2] [3 4] [5 6] [7 8 9]]` then the required result is

```
[[1 3 5 7] [2 4 6 8] [9]]
```

How to do it in clojure?

Comment: You could use something like `(apply mapv vector a)`. Though, it won't work for your second example.

Comment: possible duplicate of [matrix transposition in clojure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347315/matrix-transposition-in-clojure)

Comment: Your requirements for uneven matrices is very strange. Your example input will produce the same output as, say, `[[1 2] [3 4 9] [5 6] [7 8]]`, but matrix transposition is supposed to be an invertible operation. How important is it to support these broken "matrices"? If that requirement is dropped, then I would take @schaueho's advice and close this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like [**ifett**'s implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29235637/1202461), though it seems weird to use  [reduce-kv](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce-kv) to build a vector that could be easily build with [map](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/map)/[mapv](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/mapv).

So, here is how I would've done it:

```clj
(defn transpose [v]
  (mapv (fn [ind]
          (mapv #(get % ind)
                (filter #(contains? % ind) v)))
        (->> (map count v)
             (apply max)
             range)))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(persistent!
  (reduce
   (fn [acc e]
     (reduce-kv
      (fn [acc2 i2 e2]
        (assoc! acc2 i2 ((fnil conj []) (get acc2 i2) e2)))
      acc
      e))
   (transient [])
   [[1 2 3] [:a :b] [\a] [111] [200 300 400 500]]))

;;=> [[1 :a \a 111 200] [2 :b 300] [3 400] [500]]
```

An empty vector can be updated via the update-in fn at the 0th index, a non-empty vector can be, additionally, updated at the index immediately following the last value.

The reduction here is about passing the outer accumulator to the inner reducing function, updating it accordingly, and then returning it back to the outer reducing function, which in turn will pass again to the inner rf for processing the next element.

EDIT: Updated to fastest version.

Answer (score 1):

```
(->> (range)
     (map (fn [i]
            (->> a
                 (filter #(contains? % i))
                 (map #(nth % i)))))
     (take-while seq))
```

*Notice that this algorithm creates a lazy seq of lazy seqs so you that you will only pay for the transformations you really consume. If you insist on creating vectors instead, wrap the forms in `vec` at the necessary places - or if you are using Clojurescript or don't mind a Clojure 1.7 alpha use **transducers** to create vectors eagerly without paying for laziness or immutability:*

```
(into []
      (comp
       (map (fn [i]
              (into [] (comp (filter #(contains? % i))
                             (map #(nth % i)))
                    a)))
       (take-while seq))
      (range))
```

Comment: Nice solution, though it won't be able to process some inputs with `nil` values, e.g. `[[1 nil 2] [:a nil :b]]`.

Answer (score 1):

I find this easy to understand:

```
(defn nth-column [matrix n]
  (for [row matrix] (nth row n)))

(defn transpose [matrix]
  (for [column (range (count (first matrix)))]
    (nth-column matrix column)))

(transpose a)
=> ((1 3 5) (2 4 6))
```

`nth-column` is a list comprehension generating a sequence from the nth element of each sequence (of rows).

Then `transpose-matrix` is simply iterating over the columns creating a sequence element for each, consisting of `(nth-column matrix column)` i.e. the sequence of elements for that column.

Answer (score -1):

```
(map 
    (partial filter identity) ;;remove nil in each sub-list
    (take-while 
        #(some identity %) ;;stop on all nil sub-list
        (for [i (range)] 
            (map #(get % i) a)))) ;; get returns nil on missing values
```

Use get to have nil on missing values, iterate (for) on an infinite range, stop on all nil sub-list, remove nil from sub-lists. Add vector constructor before first map and in it's function (first argument) if you really need vectors.

EDIT: please leave a comment if you think this is not useful. We can all learn from mistakes.