# Clojure : idiomatic weighted mean of vectors

Tags: clojure

I would like to compute the weighted mean of vectors in an idiomatic way.
To illustrate what I want, imagine I have this data :

data 1 = [2 1] , weight 1 = 1
data 2 = [3 4], weight 2 = 2

Then mean = [(2*1 + 3*2)/(1+2) (1*1 + 2*4)/(1+2)] = [2.67 3.0]

Here is my code :

```
(defn meanv
  "Returns the vector that is the mean of input ones.
   You can also pass weights just like apache-maths.stats/mean"
  ([data]
   (let [n (count (first data))]
     (->> (for [i (range 0 n)]
            (vec (map (i-partial nth i) data)))
          (mapv stats/mean))))
  ([data weights]
   (let [n (count (first data))]
     (->> (for [i (range 0 n)]
            (vec (map (i-partial nth i) data)))
          (mapv (i-partial stats/mean weights))))))
```

Then

```
(meanv [[2 1] [3 4]] [1 2]) = [2.67 3.0]
```

Few notes :

`stats/means` takes 1 or 2 inputs.
One input version has weights = 1 by default.
Two inputs is the weighted version.

`i-partial` is like partial but the fn has reversed args

```
Ex : ((partial / 2) 1) = 2  
     ((i-partial / 2) 1 = 1/2
```

So my function works, no problem.
But in a way I would like to implement it in a more idiomatic Clojure.

I tried many combinations with things like `(map (fn [&xs ...` but it does not work.
Is it possible to take all nth elements of undefined number of vectors and directly apply stats/mean ? I mean a one-liner

Thanks

**EDIT** (birdspider answer)

```
(defn meanv
  ([data]
   (->> (apply mapv vector data)
        (mapv stats/mean)))
  ([data weights]
   (->> (apply mapv vector data)
        (mapv (i-partial stats/mean weights)))))
```

And with

```
(defn transpose [m]
  (apply mapv vector m))

(defn meanv
  ([data]
   (->> (transpose data)
        (mapv stats/mean)))
  ([data weights]
   (->> (transpose data)
        (mapv (i-partial stats/mean weights)))))
```

Comment: why are both datas divided by `(1+2)` ?

Comment: nvm, it gets divided by weights' sum

Comment: I'm confused - in your textual descr you say data is `[ [2 1] [3 4] ]` weight is `[1 2]` - in your sample you use `[ [1 2] [3 4] ]` - so which one is it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing you want to do is to transpose the matrix (get the firsts, seconds, thirds, etc.)

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347404/2645347) SO page.

```
; https://stackoverflow.com/a/10347404/2645347
(defn transpose [m]
  (apply mapv vector m))
```

Then I would do it as follows, input checks are utterly absent.

```
(defn meanv
  ([data]
   ; no weigths default to (1 1 1 ...
   (meanv data (repeat (count data) 1)))) 
  ([data weigths]
   (let [wf (mapv #(partial * %) weigths) ; vector of weight mult fns
         wsum (reduce + weigths)]
     (map-indexed
      (fn [i datum]
        (/
         ; map over datum apply corresponding weight-fn - then sum
         (apply + (map-indexed #((wf %1) %2) datum)) 
         wsum))
      (transpose data)))))

(meanv [[2 1] [3 4]] [1 2]) => (8/3 3) ; (2.6666 3.0)
```

Profit!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see where is your logic tough it is hard to evaluate your post since it does the mean calculation job. I will try to merge it with my mean-fn  and see if it's better !

Comment: Ok I tried it, obviously better ! Edited my post with the merge

Answer (score 1):

```
(def mult-v (partial mapv *))
(def sum-v (partial reduce +))
(def transpose (partial apply mapv vector))

(defn meanv [data weights]
  (->> data
       transpose
       (map (partial mult-v weights))
       (map sum-v)
       (map #(/ % (sum-v weights)))))
```

Comment: `(map (comp f1 f2 f3))` since we're golfing :)

Comment: I didn't mean to golf. Just proposed my version of solving this.

Comment: Thanks too ! I just used my own fn for mean which is an apache-maths wrapper