# How to implement in Clojure unzip like in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, clojure

unzip function takes m elements with n elements each and returns n elements with m elements each, eg

```
(def pairs [[1 2] [3 4] [5 6]])

(unzip pairs) => [[1 3 5] [2 4 6]]
```

Ideally looking for something that works for arbitrary number of elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) macro is quite useful for these sorts of things:

```
(defn unzip [input]
  (for [iter (iterate (partial map rest) input)
        :while (every? seq iter)]
    (map first iter)))
```

Comment: Technically this returns lists instead of vectors, but otherwise nice.

Comment: If you define a generic `zip` first (same as [`transpose`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347315/matrix-transposition-in-clojure)), you can define unzip in terms of that as `(defn unzip [input] (apply zip input))`.

Answer (score 1):

A fairly ugly solution I came up with for 2 sequences unzipped is:

```
(defn- reducer-fn [{:keys [firsts seconds]} [f s]]
  {:firsts (conj firsts f)
   :seconds (conj seconds s) })

(defn- split2 [{:keys [firsts seconds]}]
  [[firsts seconds]])

(defn unzip2 [input]
  (->> input
       (reduce reducer-fn {:firsts [] :seconds []})
       split2))
```